# ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception in map task

Tags: java, arrays, hadoop, mapreduce, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to split the input value into 3 parts and assign each parts to a separate string and do some operations on that. But I am getting ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception and I couldn't figure out the reason.

Mapper:

```
public void map (Object Key, Text value,Context context )throws IOException,InterruptedException{

    String text=value.toString();
    String date =null;
    String parts[]=tweet.split("\\t");
    String sentence= parts[0].toString();

    for(int i=0;i<parts.length;i++) {
        System.out.println("part "+i+parts[i]);
    }

    if(parts.length>0){
        date=parts[1];
    }

    word.set(date);
    context.write(word, one);
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
2015-07-31 16:50:50,288 INFO  [Thread-11] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:run(397)) - Map task executor complete.
2015-07-31 16:50:50,295 WARN  [Thread-11] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:run(482)) - job_local467783972_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:403)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1      
    *at sw$TweetMapper.map(sw.java:103)* --> points to date=parts[1]
    at sw$TweetMapper.map(sw.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

the parts[] length is more than 0 but even  then the assignment cause the error.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: input - *some text* \t 11-12-2014 \t *some text*

Comment: your exception is at line 103 of sw.java file

Comment: `if(parts.length>0){ date=parts[1]; }` You know that this check is insufficient? If `length == 1`, then `parts[1];` would throw the mentioned exception ... so I guess you don't know, that it is insufficient.

Comment: @DeepakGoyal : yes, the line 103 is date=parts[1]

Comment: `if(parts.length>0){date=parts[1];}` is the issue. Pretty sure you mean to assign it to `parts[0]`.

Comment: just output the length of parts and let me know what it is. Because if length is only 1 then it always give you exception.

Comment: @Tom: Thanks for pointing it out !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I believe you should be using `\t` for the tab literal in split, instead of `\\t`, since that will attempt to split on the actual string `"\t"`. Hence:</s>

```
String parts[] = tweet.split("\t");
```

`parts.length > 0` doesn't sufficiently guard you against an out-of-bounds exception. As you can see in your case, just because the length is greater than zero doesn't mean that there is an element at `parts[1]`; you should be checking if the length is greater than 1:

```
if(parts.length > 1) {
    date = parts[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! But there was no issue in using "\\t". It gave me the expected output. Like Tom and you mentioned, the issue was in the insufficient check , if(parts.length > 0) , when I changed it to if(parts.length > 1) , there was no problem.

Comment: @Tom Wow, I stand corrected. I guess that does work!

Comment: @VivinPaliath I guess so :D. And I guess that OPs `tweet` doesn't have "real" tabs.